# SwiftUI: How to sort/filter @Published array for presentation purposes only

Tags: swiftui-list

(Using XCode 13.4 / iOS 15)

I have a `@Published` array that is presented to the user in a `List` with the ability to make changes to the items. The source of the array is from a file that is updated once the user makes changes to the items.

The sample code below shows how I'm currently doing that.

My question is: I want the `List` that is presented to the user to be sorted. How can I do that without changing the underlying `@Published` array, while still enabling the user to make changes to the items?

```
struct Contact: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var dateOfBirth: Date
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contacts: [Contact]
    
    static let shared = ViewModel()
    private init() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        
        let sampleData = [
            Contact(firstName: "James", lastName: "Smith", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "2-Jan-1965")!),
            Contact(firstName: "John", lastName: "Johnson", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "7-Feb-1982")!),
            Contact(firstName: "David", lastName: "Brown", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "22-Mar-1971")!),
            Contact(firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Jones", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "15-Aug-2002")!),
            Contact(firstName: "Robert", lastName: "Davis", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "11-Nov-2010")!),
        ]
        
        contacts = sampleData
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($viewModel.contacts) {$contact in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(contact.firstName) \(contact.lastName)")
                    DatePicker("", selection: $contact.dateOfBirth, displayedComponents: [.date])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any missing info in my question that I should add? Will appreciate any direction on how to solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of experimenting and investigations I came up with a solution.
The trick was to transform the `Binding` `Array` of the `ObservedObject` (e.g. `Binding<[Contact]>`) into `Array of Binding` (e.g. `[Binding<Contact>]`). This enabled presenting the data in different ways while having the `Binding` bounded to the original items.

It boils down to one computed property that transforms and return the data to be presented:

```
private var filteredContacts: [Binding<Contact>] {
    
    /// `$viewModel.contacts` is of type `Binding<[Contact]>`. We are creating an array
    /// of `Binding<Contact>` from the source `viewModel.contact`
    let contactBindingsArr = $viewModel.contacts.map {$contact in return $contact}
    
    // Sort/Filter the array of Bindings
    let res = contactBindingsArr.filter{contact in ![2,4,6].contains(contact.id) }.sorted{$0.id > $1.id}
    
    return res
}
```

Here is the code of a fully working example. There are three `List` views: first is showing the original data, second is showing filtered data and third is showing grouped data. It also shows behavior when adding a new item.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Contact: Identifiable {
    let id: Int // = UUID()
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var dateOfBirth: Date
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contacts: [Contact]
    
    static let shared = ViewModel()
    private init() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        
        let sampleData = [
            Contact(id: 1, firstName: "James", lastName: "Smith", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "2-Jan-1965")!),
            Contact(id: 5, firstName: "John", lastName: "Johnson", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "7-Feb-2022")!),
            Contact(id: 2, firstName: "David", lastName: "Brown", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "22-Mar-1965")!),
            Contact(id: 4, firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Jones", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "15-Aug-2022")!),
            Contact(id: 3, firstName: "Robert", lastName: "Davis", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "11-Nov-1965")!),
        ]
        
        contacts = sampleData
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel.shared
    
    private var groupedContacts:[GroupedContacts] {
        
        /// `$viewModel.contacts` is of type `Binding<[Contact]>`. We are creating an array
        /// of `Binding<Contact>` from the source `viewModel.contact`
        let contactBindingsArr = $viewModel.contacts.map {$contact in return $contact}
        
        // Group contacts by year of the dateOfBirth
        let dict = Dictionary(grouping: contactBindingsArr, by: {$item in item.dateOfBirth.formatted(.dateTime.year())})
        var arr = dict.keys.map { GroupedContacts(key: $0, contacts: dict[$0]!.sorted{$0.id > $1.id}) }
        arr.sort { $0.key > $1.key }

        return arr
    }
    
    private var filteredContacts: [Binding<Contact>] {
        
        /// `$viewModel.contacts` is of type `Binding<[Contact]>`. We are creating an array
        /// of `Binding<Contact>` from the source `viewModel.contact`
        let contactBindingsArr = $viewModel.contacts.map {$contact in return $contact}
        
        // Sort/Filter the array of Bindings
        let res = contactBindingsArr.filter{contact in ![2,4,6].contains(contact.id) }.sorted{$0.id > $1.id}
        
        return res
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                // This list shows the original data
                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.contacts) {contact in
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(contact.id). \(contact.firstName) \(contact.lastName)")
                            Spacer()
                            Text(contact.dateOfBirth.formatted(.dateTime.year().month().day()))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .border(Color.red)
                
                // This list shows sorted/filtered data
                List {
                    ForEach(filteredContacts) {$contact in
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(contact.id). \(contact.firstName) \(contact.lastName)")
                            DatePicker("", selection: $contact.dateOfBirth, displayedComponents: [.date])
                        }
                    }
                }
                .border(Color.blue)
                
                // This list shows grouped data
                List {
                    ForEach(groupedContacts, id: \.key) {group in
                        Section(content: {
                            ForEach(group.contacts) {$contact in
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(contact.id). \(contact.firstName) \(contact.lastName)")
                                    DatePicker("", selection: $contact.dateOfBirth, displayedComponents: [.date])
                                }
                            }
                        }, header: {Text("Year Of \(group.key)")})
                        
                    }
                }
                .border(Color.orange)
                
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("\(Image(systemName: "plus"))") {
                        let formatter = DateFormatter()
                        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
                        let maxId = (viewModel.contacts.max {a, b in a.id < b.id})?.id ?? 0
                        let newContact = Contact(id: maxId + 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", dateOfBirth: formatter.date(from: "18-May-2022")!)
                        viewModel.contacts.append(newContact)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private struct GroupedContacts {
        let key:String
        let contacts:[Binding<Contact>]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just as follows:

```
var filteredList: [ListItems] {
    modelData.listItems.filter { entry in
        (!showFavoritesOnly || entry.isFavorite)
        
    }
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
                Text("Favorites only")
            }
            ForEach(filteredList) { currentItem in
                NavigationLink{
                    ItemDetail(item: currentItem)
                } label: {
                    ItemRow(landmark: currentItem)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Components")
    }
}
```

Here I have a List that is being filtered to "show favorites only," when the user determines to do so. To achieve this, the model of my ListItems has a boolean, `isFavorite`, that is flipped when the user chooses to make the item a favorite. I then filter here (if the toggle switch is on) to check which items are favorites.

For you, you should add a boolean to `Contact()` that you can look at to specifically filter out anything that is true or false.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't address the requirement to enable the user to edit the item. In my example, each item in the `ForEach` body is getting a `Binding` that allows making changes (e.g. with the `DatePicker`)

Comment: Sorry, if I'm understanding you correctly, to enable editing of the items you can either do a NavagationLink (inside the ForEach, on each item) to another view where you edit the items inside. In my example I do a navigation link that goes to an Items Detail page. On the detail page, users can edit the item. You could also use `.popover()` if you don't want to go to an entirely new view to do editing.